# How to bind on a prop of type object using v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

referring to [this link](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)  i am trying to implement the example shown in section titled `Binding Multiple Properties Using an Object`.

i have the following object in the parent compoent:

```
const post = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'My Journey with Vue'
}
```

and i want to pass it to the child component using `v-bind`, so i coded the parent component as shown below in the code, ans the child component is as shown below as well.
the problem is, at the run time, the `{{ post }}` in the child-component is empty.

please let me know how can i canonically bing on properties using `v-bind`

**note**:

i know how to bind on props of a child-component, as shown in the follwoing example:

```
    **parent-component**:
        <component :is="HelloWorld" :msg="m" :id="posts.id" :title="posts.title"/>
    **child-component**:
        <template>
          <div class="hello">
            msg:{{msg}}
            <br/>
            postId:{{id}}
            <br/>
            postTitle:{{title}}             
          </div>
        </template>
```

**parent.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <component :is="HelloWorld" :msg="m" v-bind="post"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const post = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'My Journey with Vue'
}
</script>
```

**child-component**:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    msg:{{msg}}
    <br/>
    posts:{{post}}
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
    post:Object,
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should do `<component :is="HelloWorld" :msg="m" :post="post"/>`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim but in the link i provided, it is stated that i can use `v-bind` !!would you please check the link?

Comment: `:<prop>` is short syntax for `v-bind:<prop>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `v-bind="someObject"`, its properties will be destructed and you should have that properties defined as props in child component :

**Child** :

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    msg:{{msg}}
    <br/>
    post title:{{title}}
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
    id: String,
    title : String
  }
}
</script>
```